# Public Function Not Returning Value

Tags: java, android

I am trying to calculate the difference between two dates but the function is not returning the value

I am calling the function like this

```
GeneralMethods generalMethods = new GeneralMethods();
generalMethods.daysPassed(contacts_update_date, currentDate);
```

And the function is as follows

```
public class GeneralMethods {

    public long daysPassed(String contacts_update_date, String currentDate) {

        // Calculate Time Passed

        long diff;
        long timePassed = 0;

        SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");
        String inputString1 = contacts_update_date;
        String inputString2 = currentDate;

        try {
            Date date1 = myFormat.parse(inputString1);
            Date date2 = myFormat.parse(inputString2);
            diff = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
            timePassed = TimeUnit.DAYS.convert(diff, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return timePassed;

    }

}
```

Finally I am using the value like this

```
if (timePassed > 30) { 
//do something 
}
```

Comment: what does it return? perhaps catching the exception is not a good idea

Comment: you call the method, but you don't assign nor use the returned value

Comment: Maybe you need to assign the result of `generalMethods.daysPassed(contacts_update_date, currentDate);` to a variable?

Comment: I am trying to use the value of timePassed please see my edit

Comment: maybe you are having a `ParseException`?

Comment: code is working fine if I use it without it being a function... as soon as i put it in a function and try to return timePassed it stops working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this

```
GeneralMethods generalMethods = new GeneralMethods();
long timePassed=generalMethods.daysPassed(contacts_update_date, currentDate);
```

Comment: What are your input dates and what is the output?

Comment: 26 02 2019  and 26 02 2019

Comment: wait i am rechecking your answer dates could be the issue